# Setup Postfix using an external SMTP Server

Tags: server, email, postfix

I am trying to set up postfix on Ubuntu 14.04 to use an external SMTP Server.

I installed the `libsasl2-modules` to deal with authentication.

I created my credentials file:

```
sudo vim /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

using:

```
[mail.mydomain.com]:587 username:password
```

Created the hash db:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Used this settings in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
#myhostname = web.mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = www.mydomain.com, web.mydomain.com, localhost.mydomain.com, localhost
relayhost = [mail.mydomain.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# enable SASL authentication 
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication. 
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# where to find sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption 
smtp_use_tls = yes
# where to find CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

However, whenever I send a test mail authentication fails because `postfix` is not using my credentials at `sasl_passwd` but the current user instead. Please check my `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Mar  4 09:10:20 web postfix/smtp[9214]: 4087042522: to=<myadress@gmail.com>, relay=mail.mydomain.com[xx.xx.xxx.xx]:587, delay=4.9, delays=4.8/0.01/0.12/0.01, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.mydomain.com[xx.xx.xxx.xx] said: 550-Verification failed for <root@mydomain.com> 550-No Such User Here 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

`Verification failed for <root@mydomain.com>` When I want to use my username:password in sasl_passwd.

I can't find documentation on how to dig into this. Why `postfix` is not using the the sasl_passw file?

Comment: Not sure it's 100% necessary but I have the line `smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login` in my main.cf file.

Comment: Thanks @Arronical, just tried it, restarted postfix and same error.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone with same problem, I just created email accounts at my ISP for each user in the machine sending emails (`root@mydomain.com`, `users@mydomain.com`, and `apache-user@mydomain.com`) and works.